# strptime - ValueError: time data '02/08/18 10:47:43,907000000' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, error-handling

I have time data stored in my pandas dataframe as string and want to get it to datetime. One entry looks like this:

```
02/08/18 10:47:43,907000000
```

I use this code in order to get it done:

```
df['Datetime'] = df['TIME'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f"))
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '02/08/18 10:47:43,907000000' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f'
```

How do I have to modify my code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the format error `%Y` vs `%y`, use `pd.to_datetime` instead of `apply`:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S,%f")
```

You can also let Pandas guess the format for you (which might be slower):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
```

Comment: Yes, this worked out correctly! Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your year formatter should be in lowercase (`%y`), not uppercase (`%Y`).

Giving:

`'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S,%f'`

Comment: Yes, it seems to work better but I now get this error: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 000`.

Comment: microseconds are only 6 digits long. So the last three zeros are not converted.